# Firebase get all users in a parent node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a simple friend list, where the user can create some friend groups and each friend group can have a lot of friends, inside the friend group the user can add new friends by contact(inserting the phone number on a editText) the user is added in the list(I use recycleViews), each time I insert a new user in a friendList group in firebase it is added inside the group with the specific name(name can't be repeated for groups) with the userID and the value = true for that user, this is a representation of my firebase:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDpI2.png) the 't' refers to true

what I need, is to display all the users for a specific group, as long as I safe just the id inside my group, I need to get the entire user from that id, but not just 1 user I need to get them all.

So I did this:

```
 private void prepareFriendList() {
        myRef.child(id).child("FriendLists").child(group).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    currentFriends.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        myRef.child(id).child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    for(String item: currentFriends){
                        if (snapshot.getKey().equals(item)) {
                            usersList.add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: "So i did this" and what? Tell us why it didnt work

Comment: the users don't appear when i enter the group :/

Comment: and im confused, if this is the way how it should be done using firebase with android